# Ruby gems.. exporting to server?

Tags: ruby, api, rubygems

I'm new to ruby gems and I'm wondering.. if I was using an API from Ruby gems to write a script and I then exported the script to a server for it to run there, would I have to install the gem on the server? Is there know way for me to bundle it up into 1 file I just run? (like a Java jar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply include your gem in your gem file, then when you deploy and run `bundle install` on the server it will get all your dependencies including your gem

Answer (score 2):

`bundle package` will package all your gems into your rails app.

Comment: This makes an assumption of Rails that the OP didn't state.

Answer (score 1):

Bundler install your gem for you , but it dosn't include the gem in your script.
if you dont have many dependencies you could try to simple unpack the gem in to a folder , you have to require the gem following your relative path , the main problem is if some of your gem have to compile native code (like hpricot) . 
use

```
gem unpack GEMNAME
```

into your script folder and then locate the main file to require in your code (usualy in a lib direcotory into the unpacked gem) .
this work easly only for simple gems without chain dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just create a vendor directory in my application and extract your gems there.  `gem unpack gem_name` will do it for you or you can use Rails' `rake gem:unpack GEM=gem_name`.

Bundler is another great solution but if you just want a quick and dirty solution then just unpack the gem into your application and be done with it.